# "drive by" = "drive near"?

Tags: prepositions

Is it correct to say "drive by London", "drive by the beach" in the  meaning of "near London", "near the beach"?

Comment: Without some context and a full sentence, it is impossible to say whether "drive by London", "drive by the beach"" is correct use of "by". "Drive by London" is unlikely to be correct.

Comment: Welcome to English Language & Usage. Would you share with us your research, please? It would make it easier to respond if we did not duplicate what you have already done.

Answer (score 2):

'Drive by' means 'go past'. You might decide the route for your car journey:

> We will drive by London on the way to Cornwall.

although it's more idiomatic to say

> We will drive to Cornwall via London.

---

The 'beach' example is more idiomatic:

> Let's drive by the beach to take a look at what the surf is like.

---

In fact **drive-by** has become an adjective as given by [Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/definition/drive-by)

> **drive-by**
> ADJECTIVE
> (of a shooting or other act) carried out from a passing vehicle.

and even a noun

> **drive-by**
> NOUN
> A shooting carried out from a passing vehicle..

Comment: I'm not sure the first two examples are quite so similar in meaning as you make out: the former suggests a route involving the M25 and the latter suggests one passing closer to Charing Cross.

Comment: @BrianDonovan I'd agree with that, in fact I think a better example might be "We drove by Swindon on the way to Cornwall" since most of the main roads, and especially the M4, pass close to Swindon but do not go through it.

Comment: @BoldBen my draft had said "instead of Birmingham." The doubts might be linguistically valid, but why would you go into central London when you are headed for Cornwall?

Comment: @WeatherVane:Perhaps to pick up Aunt Augusta, who just adores Penzance.

Comment: @BrianDonovan nice one, so "We will drive via Aunt Agatha's." We certainly won't drive *by* it. She would be very annoyed by a drive-by without picking her up.

Comment: @WeatherVane It wasn't me who suggested London, but it would depend where you started from. You might be tempted to go straight through if you lived in Brentwood.

Comment: @BoldBen that's true, but with the congestion and emission charges? Going via Birmingham suggests an origin further north.

Comment: @WeatherVane If you were setting off at night and were more concerned with the time than the cost (or were driving an exempt vehicle) you could well think it was worth it.

Comment: @BoldBen for Brentwood to Heathrow google maps gives 57 minutes via M25, 1:27 via North Circular and 1:37 via central London and A4. You'll be hard pushed to beat a motorway journey, even when the traffic is stop-go.

Comment: This is starting to remind me of [G. K. Chesterton's poem "The Rolling English Road"](https://www.poetryfoundation.org/poems/48212/the-rolling-english-road) with its reference to "The night we went to Birmingham by way of Brighton Pier."